# Ruby to_f is returning nothing or 0.0

Tags: ruby

String to float conversion using `to_f` is not working for me.

I'm trying pick a column from the longitude and latitude data as below.

```
"136.98355","35.130433333333336","2013-07-31T22:37:12+09:00","2346","13066","42","0","0","0"
"136.98363333333333","35.1306","2013-07-31T22:38:13+09:00","1311","13580","41","0","0","0"
"136.98361666666668","35.130583333333334","2013-07-31T22:39:13+09:00","3946","13580","41","0","0","0"
```

When I simply grab the column using the below code, it works.

```
ruby -e "STDIN.readlines.each do |line| col = line.chomp.split(','); puts col[0] end" < new.csv > picked_nagoya.csv
```

Result:

```
"136.98355"
"136.98363333333333"
"136.98361666666668"
```

But when I apply `to_f` to convert strings into floats, the file `picked_nagoya.csv` is empty.

I tried to work it around by storing converted string into a variable and then writing it out to the file. However, it then returns 0.0s.

```
ruby -e "STDIN.readlines.each do |line| col = line.chomp.split(','); f =  col[0].to_f; puts f end" < new.csv > picked_nagoya.csv
```

Result:

```
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your example looks like your file is a CSV file. Did you consider using a CSV parser?

Comment: For csv parsing you could use mlr / miller https://github.com/johnkerl/miller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `to_f` is expecting a number, but the first character of the string you're trying to convert is actually a quotation mark: `"123.456"`

You'll need to trim the quotes off the string before you do any conversion:

```
f = col[0].delete_prefix('"').delete_suffix('"').to_f
```

Comment: "You'll need to trim the quotes" - Or use a CSV parser

Comment: Use a CSV parser. It's there to make life easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I realized it right after I posted ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Ruby CSV parser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.0.preview2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) you can extract the data and work with this:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.readlines('data.csv').each do |row|
  lat, lng = row.first(2).map(&:to_f)

  p [ lat, lng ]
end
```

Gives you output like:

```
[136.98355, 35.130433333333336]
[136.98363333333333, 35.1306]
[136.98361666666668, 35.130583333333334]
```